# Combinations of multisets with finite multiplicities

Tags: co.combinatorics, reference-request

The question may be of little interest to most people here on MathOverflow, but after browsing a pile of books in combinatorics, I had to ask it somewhere:

What are the most efficient formulae for calculating the number of $k$-combinations (and $k$-permutations) of multisets with finite multiplicities (i.e. combinations and permutations with repetition, but with restrictions on the number of repetition)?

I know that generating functions are often used for solving this kind of problems, but there has been a number of formulae used for such counting, such as Percy MacMahon's one ($m_i$ denotes multiplicities of $n$ different elements in the multiset):

$$C(k;m_{1},m_{2},\ldots,m_{n})=\sum_{p=0}^{n}(-1)^{p}\sum_{1\le i_{1}\le i_{2}\le\cdots\le i_{p}\le n}{n+k-m_{i_{1}}-m_{i_{2}}-\ldots-m_{i_{p}}-p-1 \choose n-1}$$

Are you aware of other formulae for it, or useful references in literature?

EDIT: Clearing up the statement: a $k$-combination means simply picking $k$ elements from the multiset (order not important). $k$-permutation is basically the same, but order is important. In the example above, the multiset is $\{ m_1\cdot a_1,m_2\cdot a_2,\ldots m_n\cdot a_n\}$, $a_i$  being the elements, $m_i$  being the multiplicities.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what a k-combination or a k-permutation is.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not making it clear: a $k$-combination means simply picking k terms from the multiset (order not important). $k$-permutation is basically the same, but order is important. In the example above, the multiset is $\{m_1\cdot a_1, m_2\cdot a_2,\ldots,m_n\cdot a_n\}$, $a_i$ being the elements, $m_i$ being the multiplicities.

Comment: Have you looked at Knuth's Volume 4 fascicle 3, in particular exercise 39 in section 7.2.1.4?

Comment: @András: looking it right now - but I don't see how a formula for combinations I'm looking for could directly follow from a formula for partitions given there?

Comment: [Related question here on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/67359/41291) with [an answer by Richard Stanley](http://mathoverflow.net/a/67365/41291)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the OP's 2011 paper with Ž. Jurić:

[A New Formula for the Number of Combinations of Permutations of Multisets](http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2011/ams-17-20-2011/siljakAMS17-20-2011.pdf)
*Applied Mathematical Sciences*, Vol. 5, 2011, no. 18, 875-881

there is a paper by Thomas Wieder, also in 2011:

[Generation of All Possible Multiselections from a Multiset](http://www.cscanada.net/index.php/pam/article/view/j.pam.1925252820110201.010)
*CSCanada Progress in Applied Mathematics*, Vol. 2, No. 1, 2011, pp. 61-66

which approaches counting the $k$-combinations of a multiset (sub-multisets of a multiset) in terms of "selection matrices" (similar to contingency tables).

In addition to the references cited in these two papers, Frank Ruskey's 2003 work-in-progress [Combinatorial Generation](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Efelsner/SemWS17-18/Ruskey-Comb-Gen.pdf) has Sec. 4.5.1 with algorithms based on representing $k$-combinations as *weak compositions with restricted parts*.